# Converting showoff presentation to LaTeX

Tags: export, latex, presentations

Is there a way to convert a ShowOff presentation to LaTeX?

Apparently, ShowOff uses Maruku as a renderer, and Maruku supports LaTeX, so it should be possible, but I'm wondering how to do it.